# which rule is being applied here?

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

[image]

My css is as follows:

```
ion-item.comment-format {
  white-space : normal!important;
}
```

and the html is :

```
 <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="comment in vm.comments" class="comment-format">
```

From the image above, I expected the comment-format rule to apply but it is only when I toggle white space with nowrap (which has a line through it) does it apply. I was expecting my first rule to apply. Clearly my understanding of rules is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

css property `white-space:nowrap` is not applied in you page because it is overwritten with other css `white-space:normal !important`.

If there are two same css with different declarations is there for one element and one is declared with `!important` then no matter which css is first the css declared with `!important` will work only.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, but that is what I expected. What I am seeing is white-space:normal !important is not being applied. Only when I toggle white-space:nowrap does the white-space:normal !important get applied. I wanted the normal rule to be applied and not nowrap.

Comment: u need to uncheck the nowrap property?

Comment: Yes, that is what I see. If I create another Div below ng-repeat, and apply the rule (white-space:normal) then it works as expected. But if I have the rule on the ng-repeat (with the class item), I had to uncheck nowrap in dev tools to get the white-space:normal rule to be applied.

Comment: could you please share a fiddle because according to me if you use `!important` then only the css with important will apply.